# response writer does not contain flusher

Tags: go, server-sent-events, grpc-go

i am trying to learn Server sent events, where after every write we need to call flush , but it is not finding http.flush in **http.ResponseWriter, it always throws error http.Flusher: missing method Flush**, what could have gone here ? will update with reproducible code

```
func serverSideEvent(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
if r.URL.Path != "/stream" {
    http.Error(w, "404 not found.", http.StatusNotFound)
    return
}

if r.Method != "GET" {
    http.Error(w, "Method is not supported.", http.StatusNotFound)
    return
}
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
w.Header().Set("Connection", "keep-alive")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "data: %d\n\n", i)
    w.(http.Flusher).Flush()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}
```

}

Comment: @mkopriva the error is at runtime, also i am able to run go build

Comment: You must show your actual server and all middleware.

Comment: @AmanRAJ I see, then as Volker's comment implies, it's likely that some code in-between the server and the handler has wrapped the ResponseWriter into a type that doesn't implement the flusher interface. *"The default HTTP/1.x and HTTP/2 ResponseWriter implementations support Flusher, __but ResponseWriter wrappers may not__."* https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.19.5#Flusher